# Gramian determinant and line integral of a vector field

Tags: analysis, manifolds, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

When we do a line integral over a scalar field, I understand this as a special case of an Integral over a one-dimensional real manifold. Getting the volume (in this case "length" as a 1-dim. volume) of the manifold involves using the  gramian determinant. Now, an integral over a vectorfield should follow  the same principle. But where  does it make use of the gramian determinant?

What the method seems to do, is doing a projection of the vectorfield at that point onto the tangent space of the curve.  And summing up all those projections lengths.
[Like in this animation.](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b0/Line_integral_of_vector_field.gif)
But maybe this flawed: a projection needs the vector we project onto to be of length 1. In this (infinitesimal) sum it is not.

Comment: When you compute the work done by a vector field $\vec F$ along a curve, you are integrating the scalar function $\vec F\cdot\vec T$ (here $\vec T$ is the unit tangent vector of the curve).

Comment: But doesnt that rely on the assumption that the gradient of the curve (which gives us the basis of our tangent space) is of length one? If yes, why is that? If not, why can we do that?

Comment: No, not at all. If the curve is parametrized by $\vec g(t)$, note that $$\vec F\cdot \vec T\,ds = \vec F(\vec g(t))\cdot \frac{\vec g'(t)}{\|\vec g'(t)\|}\|\vec g'(t)\|dt = \vec F(\vec g(t))\cdot \vec g'(t)\,dt.$$